# How to speed up a nested loop of 3.6 million records in python?

Tags: python

I have a companies.json file with 3.6 million records (Every record contains an id & vat number) and an event.json file with 76.000 records (+- 20 properties). I wrote a script doing the following steps:

1. Open both JSON files
2. Loop through the 76.000 event records (type is class dict)
3. Check if the status of the event is new
4. If the status is new, check if the event has a companyID
5. If the event has a companyID, loop through the 3.6 million records to find the matching company ID.
6. Check if the matching company record has a VAT number
7. Replace the companyID with the VAT number and add an companyIDIsVat boolean.
8. When all looping is done, write the events to a new JSON file.

The script is working fine but it's taking 6-7 hours to complete. Is there a way to speed it up?

**Current script**

```
import json

counter = 0;

with open('companies.json', 'r') as companiesFile:
    with open('events.json', 'r') as eventsFile:
        events = json.load(eventsFile)
        companies = json.load(companiesFile)

        for index, event in enumerate(events):
            print('Counter: ' + str(index))
            if 'status' in event:
                if(event['status'] == 'new'):
                    if 'companyID' in event:
                        for company in companies:
                            if(event['companyID'] == company['_id']):
                                if 'vat' in company:
                                    event['companyID'] = company['vat']
                                    event['companyIDIsVat'] = 1
                                    counter = counter + 1
                                    print('Found matches: ' + str(counter))
        
        with open('new_events.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(events, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: load it into db. and only slow for the first time.

Comment: This might be better suited to [codereview.se]

Comment: you want to index on your id's so you aren't using linear search to find matching records

Comment: So this: "If the event has a companyID, loop through the 3.6 million records to find the matching company ID." is what you want to avoid. So if `company['_id']` is unique, you can just do something like `companies = {company['_id'] : company for company in companies}`, teh instead of `for company in companies: ...` you can jsut do something like `if event['companyID'] in companies: ....`

Comment: This would likely take seconds or minutes when using Pandas.

Comment: @mcsoini likely take the same amount using plain python with the approach above.

Comment: Note, you should probably save your `companies.json` in the indexed structure beforehand instead of re-creating it each time it runs, although, it would happen very fast anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the problem is that you are repeatedly searching through the entire companies list. But **lists are inefficient for searching**, because here, you must do a linear search, i.e., O(N). But you can do a constant-time search if you used a dict. Assuming you are `company['_id']` is unique. Basically, you want to index on your IDs. For constant time lookups, use a dictionary, i.e. a map (a hash map in CPython, and probably every python implementation):

```
import json

counter = 0

with open('companies.json', 'r') as companiesFile:
    with open('events.json', 'r') as eventsFile:
        events = json.load(eventsFile)
        companies = {
            c["_id"]: c for c in json.load(companiesFile)
        }

        for index, event in enumerate(events):
            print('Counter: ' + str(index))
            if 'status' in event:
                if (
                    event['status'] == 'new' 
                    and 'companyID' in event 
                    and event['companyID'] in companies
                ):
                    company = companies[event['companyID']]
                    if 'vat' in company:
                        event['companyID'] = company['vat']
                        event['companyIDIsVat'] = 1
                        counter = counter + 1
                        print('Found matches: ' + str(counter))
        
        with open('new_events.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(events, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

This is a minimal modification to your script.

You should probably just save `companies.json` in the appropriate structure.

Again, it assumes the companies are unique by ID. If not, then you could use a dictionary of lists, and it should be still significantly faster as long as there aren't many repeating ID's

Comment: This is amazing! Just ran it. A few seconds and done. Big thanks!